# How do they find this derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given: $\ f(x)= {24 \over x^2+12} $

Their derivative: $\ {dy \over dx} = {-48x \over (x^2+12)^2} $

Yet if I try the quotient rule to solve I get the following:

$$  {dy \over dx} = {(x^2+12) - 2x(24) \over (x^2+12)^2} $$
$$  = {(x^2-48x+12) \over (x^2+12)^2} $$

I also tried the product rule and ALSO received a different answer, yet somewhat closer to their solution:
$$ f(x)= {24 \over x^2+12} $$
$$  = 24(x^2+12)^{-1} $$

$$  {dy \over dx} = {(x^2+12)^{-1}  - (x^2+12)^{-2}(2x)(24)} $$
$$  = {-48x \over (x^2+12)^3} $$

Am I doing something wrong? Why are my answers different even though I am using the given rules properly(I hope)? Why is their derivative different from what I am getting?

Comment: The derivative of $x \mapsto 24$ is zero. So you shouldn't have the first term in dy/dx above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotient rule: $$f(x) = \frac {g(x)}{h(x)}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x) h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

$$f(x)= {24 \over x^2+12}$$

$$f'(x) = \frac{0\cdot(x^2 + 12) - 24\cdot 2x}{(x^2 + 12)^2} = -\frac{48x}{(x^2 + 12)^2}$$

In both cases (your use of the quotient rule and the product rule), you incorrectly derive $g(x) = 24$. The derivative of a constant is equal to zero. So: $$g'(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx}(24) = 0 \neq 1$$

Comment: needs another Tu! +1

Answer (score 2):

As copper.hat points out, the derivative of the numerator is zero, so $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x^2+12)\cdot 0-2x\cdot(24)}{(x^2+12)^2}=-\frac{48x}{(x^2+12)^2}.$$